# C# - Regular Expression(Square Brackets)

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get this text from HTML:

```
right;">672
```

here is the regex I tried to use:

```
"right;">[0-9]+"
```

however, in regex101.com it works, but in C# it doesn't because of the square brackets.

I wanted to ask, how can I use few square brackets in regex?
thank you

Comment: Is the `.` at the end of the regex supposed to be there?

Comment: "because of the square brackets" ??  How can you tell?  Add a full compiling code sample.

Comment: I meant that when you write regex it should be like this: "[0-9]"
but if I need to get 3 square brackets or more, how can I do it?

Comment: How/where/why do you need _3_ square brackets? Your question is still not clear. Edit it and try to be more clear. Add C# code..

Comment: Just thinking about this are you actually trying to get the number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there has been no attempt to answer any of the questions in a sufficient manner and your description of the problem just doesnt make sense

Answer (score 1):

Use `@` before the entire line. And I think you need to escape the `"` with `\`.

```
@"right;\">[0-9]+".
```

Comment: Whn using `@`, use `""`, not `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex

```
new Regex("right;\">\\d+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**Update**

And if you Want to use the previous regex

```
new Regex("right;\">[0-9]+")
```

you were missing backslash `\"` in your regex

Answer (score 0):

Works for me

```
string sample = "sdfgright;\">672sdf";
Regex reg = new Regex("right;\">[0-9]+");
Console.WriteLine(reg.Match(sample).Success);
```